# How to get server name inline with top output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, top

I've been given the task to use top(htop is not an option on our system) to monitor CPU usage over time. If a user is on a server and using over 100% for longer than an hour, an email alert will be sent out to an admin.

Easily enough I written the code below to give me the information I need. You can see the code and results below. The issue I'm facing is I can't figure out how to get the server name inline with each process? Having that would greatly simplify the rest of my task.

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2
3 echo "Script was run at $(date)" >> temp1
4
5 HOSTS=("list of server names")
6
7 for i in ${HOSTS[@]} ; do
8         echo $i >> temp1
9         ssh $i top -b -n 1 | tail -n +7 | awk '$9 >= 100.0' | awk '{print $2, $9, $12}' >> temp1
10 done
11

Currently this is what my script is returning. Only thing I want differently is to have the server name follow each individual process. 
serverName1 
user 187.1 MATLAB 
serverName2 
user 144.4 plasma-de+ 
user 144.4 plasma-de+ 
user 141.7 plasma-de+ 
user 138.9 mate-sett+ 
serverName3 
user 100.0 plasma-de+ 
user 100.0 plasma-de+
```

Comment: can't you either append $i to your output ?

Comment: @vfbsilva No I cannot. At least not any way I can figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh $i top -b -n 1 | tail -n +7 | awk '$9 >= 100.0' | awk -v "host=$i" '{print host, $2, $9, $12}' >> temp1
```

Comment: That was it, thanks!